# How to compare two array values using foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I want to convert this for loop into for-each loop

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i]==arr[i+1]
    {
      // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: In foreach loop you only have access to one object at a time. Your if statement would not be possible to achieve.

Comment: Note that this leads to an `IndexOutOfRangeException` at the last iteration, because `i+1` will then be `arr.Length` and, well, out of range.

Comment: You could do that by keeping track of the previous item seen, but I wouldn't do that unless working with a stream of data instead of an array.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that with a few extra lines of code. But the code given in question will break. The condition `i<arr.Length` should be replaced with `i<arr.Length-1`.

Below code will work with foreach loop (Assuming your array is an array on integers)

```
            int previousValue = arr[0];
            bool isEntered = false;
            foreach (int currentValue in arr)
            {
                if(isEntered)
                {
                    if(previousValue == currentValue)
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
                previousValue = currentValue;
                isEntered = true;
            }
```

Comment: using  `arr.Skip(1)` inside `foreach` iteration expression you can omit `isEntered` check

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
        int index=0;
        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            index++;
            if (item == arr[index])
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", item, arr[index]);

            if (index == arr.Count()-1) break;
        }
```

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya, did you get through it?

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya, it'd be nice of you giving feedback to people trying at helping you

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether your Array has at least 1 element

```
        var previousItem = arr[0];
        foreach (var item in arr.Skip(1))
        {
            if (previousItem == item)
            {
                // Do Something
            }
            previousItem = item;
        }
```